# Why is Facebook not asking for permission when logging in

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have some login code using Graph API asking for manage_pages permission. But when it hits the code below, it logs in but it doesn't ask for permission to manage the users pages.

```
FB.login(function(r) {
    //..
}, {scope: 'user_friends, publish_actions, manage_pages'});
```

It asks if the user logging in is the owner of the app, but I want it to ask manage pages even if the app user is not the owner. When I test this code using Facebook's JavaScript Test Console, it works so how does the JavaScript console do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most permissions need to get reviewed before they work for all users. Without review, `publish_actions` and `manage_pages` only work for users with a role in the App. I assume you are trying with a user who does not have a role in the App, so you don´t get asked for the additional permissions. It is called [Login Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review).

Btw, just in case you want to post to a Page "as Page": `publish_actions` is the wrong permission for that. As you can read in the docs, you would need `publish_pages` instead.